# Is it possible to use Union Query between a query and a table?

Tags: ms-access

I created an MS Access Report which is sourced from a query (which in turn is sourced to another query, since I used count function to count the number of group from another table). The report only shows one record per page but I want to print blank records down to the bottom of the report to fill the page. I have seen code examples, and it was effective, but it joins two tables, one with data, and the other is a dummy. Is it possible to join a query with a table to achieve this? And would the code be the same?

Comment: Expect yes. Try it and find out. When you encounter specific issue, post question. This can be done without 'dummy' table, just with VBA.

Comment: Without 'dummy' table? Could you please show a sample VBA code?

Comment: Bing search "access report fill page with blank lines". Here is one tutorial https://www.vb123.com.au/200310_dl_pad.htm